# generate series in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In postgres we use the below code when we need a time series data for a line chart

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date
FROM generate_series
        ( '2004-04-01'::timestamp 
        , '2005-04-01'::timestamp
        , '1 day'::interval) dd
        LEFT JOIN school_attendence on dd = school_attendence.attendence_date
```

Is there a similar function in mongodb or mongoose library that will do the job for me?

Comment: provide sample object and expected out put

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool [***mgeneratejs***](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mgeneratejs) :

```
//install mongo and down mongoinport

//install tool
$ npm install -g mgeneratejs

//generate 10000000 documents for mongodb
$ mgeneratejs '{"name": "$name", "age": "$age", "emails": {"$array": {"of": "$email", "number": 3}}}' -n 10000000 | mongoimport --uri mongodb://localhost:27017/test --collection user --mode insert
```